# Is there a libnfc android loadable kernel module?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, nfc

Does someone have the source for Android loadable kernel module for libnfc?

If not, can someone tell me how it can be done?

As final option, if you have it build already, can you share its download URL?

On a side lining question, i read that linux kernel 3.1 actually has NFC support in it. Does that mean if kernel 3.1 was ported to android then it would have inbuilt support? If so, do you know anyone who has a kernel 3.1 version for android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel 3.3 has merged the Android kernel features, and therefore now u have Android kernel 3.3 potentially to come out very soon.   NFC supports is in the drivers/nfc (kernel source) directory, take a look at the files that.   Another resource found is this:   http://appelmelk.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/porting-libnfc-to-android/ and another document:   https://docs.google.com/open?id=160clTJ-sSgHiNKd-IsFHGzZY8M9HQudYqHnp0mD09NBTPfZmm9mP_NEMV3E3 (not written by me).

Comment: That document is owned by me :P not written by me though :P
So what you are telling me is i can take Kernel 3.3 and i can use it to bootup android and it would actually start working?